# CloudWatch agent doesn't recognize presence of IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to use the CloudWatch logs agent on a RedHat instance with an IAM role attached. The role has full access to CloudWatch. I installed and setup the agent using the instructions here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html#running-ec2-step-2

Even though the IAM role is definitely attached to the instance, I keep seeing this message in /var/log/awslogs.log:

> NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

When I run `aws configure list`, I can see the details for the IAM role.

```
  Name                    Value             Type           Location
  ----                    -----             ----           --------
 profile                <not set>           None           None
 access_key     ********************        iam-role
 secret_key     ********************        iam-role
 region                us-east-1            config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

Here is the contents of `/var/awslogs/etc/aws.conf`.

```
 [plugins]
 cwlogs = cwlogs
 [default]
 region = us-east-1
```

So why can't the CloudWatch logs agent find and use the IAM role?

Comment: When installing the agent, did you press ENTER when prompted for credentials? `Press Enter if using an IAM role. Otherwise, enter your AWS access key ID.`

Comment: Check `/var/awslogs/etc/aws.conf`. If it has entries for `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`, remove them and then restart the agent.

Comment: I pressed Enter when it asked for the access and secret key. `/var/awslogs/etc/aws.conf` doesn't contain `aws_access_key_id` or `aws_secret_access_key`. Edited the OP for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after much banging my head against the wall, I finally figured out what my problem was. I'm using a proxy to enable the CloudWatch agent to communicate with CloudWatch, and I forgot to add `NO_PROXY=169.254.169.254` to `/var/awslogs/etc/proxy.conf`. So when the agent attempted to query the metadata for information about the IAM role, it tried to go through the proxy to get it. Once I added the NO_PROXY in, it worked fine.

Comment: That fixed my issue too. Thanks !